# Issue with Iterator reuse

Tags: java, iterator

In this first while I used my Iterator and everything went well ;

```
ListIterator<Client> it = people.listIterator();      
while(it.hasNext()){
  Client c = (Client)it.next();
  System.out.println(c.getValeur());
}
System.out.println("Doing some operations on my values");
```

But when i did those operations on my values

```
for (Client client : people) {
  int i = client.getValeur();
  i += 10000;
  client.setValeur(i);
}
```

And used the same iterator, I didn't Work

```
while(it.hasNext()){
  Client c = (Client) it.next();
  System.out.println(c.getValeur());
}
```

Do I have to re-initiate the index of my iterator ?

Comment: If you like it simple (who doesn't?!), you could also use a for-each loop: `for (Client c : people) { System.out.println(c.getValeur()); }`

Comment: @assylias Unless he still uses JDK4 ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, get a new one. An Iterator can't be reset or rewinded. It iterates in one direction and should be thrown away after.

Comment: Do I have to throw it away manually or does the garbage collector handle it ?

Comment: The garbage collector will do that. (sorry for confusion, there is no concept of "throwing something away" in Java)

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to re-initiate the index of my iterator ?

No, they cannot be 'wound back'.  Get a new iterator.

Comment: Technically a `ListIterator` can move backward - but it would definitely be easier to just use a new one.

Comment: Create a new iterator. It's rarely more expensive than the reset.

Answer (score 1):

Your iterator has reached the end and you have to instantiate a new one so that it points to the first element of the list.

Answer (score 1):

That's why it's not recommanded at all to use a `while` loop dealing with an `Iterator`.

Why? Because the scope is not delimited when using `while` and may cause some trouble like you   encountered.

Prefer using this pattern:

```
for(Iterator it = people.listIterator(); it.hasNext();){
   Client c = (Client)it.next();
   System.out.println(c.getValeur());
}
//can't access it right here (outside the loop) any more
```

This way, you can't reach again the iterator (that itself finishes it's job and cannot be reset) since it's now out of the scope.

**To sum up, this pattern forces you to instantiates a new `Iterator` to loop again over the collection and this is the way to do.**

Comment: I disagree.  Using a `for` loop has just as much chance to miss iterating along as using a `while`.

Comment: @Makoto Look at this http://ddweerasiri.blogspot.fr/2011/02/java-iterator-best-practices.html

Comment: Again, I feel like this goes back to remembering to place your iteration step, as opposed to it inherently being "wrong".  I won't disagree with you, but "not recommended at all" is a gross exaggeration, especially when you ensure that you keep the scope of your iterator in check.

Comment: @Makoto I've seen many bugs due to this `Iterator` "escape" that can so easily be avoided with a `for` loop. By the way, it's less a matter of taste than a good practice :)

Answer (score 0):

An iterator is one-and-done; once it reaches the end of its iteration, it's not going to pick back up from the beginning.

Instead, from the structure of your problem space alone, there shouldn't be any reason that you can't perform all operations at once within the same iterator.

```
int i = 0;
ListIterator<Client> it = people.listIterator();      
while(it.hasNext()){
    Client c = it.next();
    System.out.println(c.getValeur());
    i = client.getValeur();
    i += 10000;
    client.setValeur(i);
}
System.out.println("Doing some operations on my values");
```

Comment: To the editor:  I'm well aware that the +10000 operation could be done on the same line as retrieving the value.  However, I intentionally left it like that to make it clear.

Comment: If you do so the output would be the old then the new value for each person when what I need is the old values of all the people first then the new ones ?   Cheers

Comment: Since in your example you only print out the old values, this accomplishes the same purpose.  It then sets the new value by adding 10000 plus whatever was previously in `i`.